# STOMP: Way to check if a consumer is running before sending a message?

Tags: php, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm wondering if there is a way to check if a consumer is running before sending a message? I'm using the latest php STOMP and am struggling to see if there's a way to detect if it's running before sending and having messages just build up in queue.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: One of the main benefits of asynchronous messaging is that producers and consumers are 100% independent. Producers shouldn't care if there are any consumers. If you're having trouble with message build-up in the queue then you should configure the broker to, for example, drop/expire messages after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the BrokerStatisticsPlugin that's available in AMQ, it allows your client to send a message and have the broker send you all sorts of nice information about its current state.

See:
http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html

Regards

Tim
www.fusesource.com

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ActiveMQ [Web Console](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html) running, you can make a CURL call to the xml/queues.jsp page, which will return you XML with `<queue>` nodes looking looking like

```
<queue name="integration">
  <stats size="0" consumerCount="1" enqueueCount="92491" dequeueCount="92491"/>
  <feed>
    <atom>queueBrowse/integration?view=rss&amp;feedType=atom_1.0</atom>
    <rss>queueBrowse/integration?view=rss&amp;feedType=rss_2.0</rss>
  </feed>
</queue>
```

You're looking for the `consumerCount` attribute of the `<stats>` node.

Comment: Ah, that's in interesting approach. I ended up going with doing a grep of the ps -aux